# How many outcomes does the chess tournament have?

Tags: combinatorics

Two players are in a chess tournament. The tournament is won either by winning 2 consecutive games or by winning 3 games in total. No match ends with a draw. How many possible outcomes does the tournament have?

The answer is 10, and here are the outcomes (A and B are the players, the letter indicates the winner):

$AA\: BB\: ABB\: BAA\: ABAA\: BABB\: ABABB\: BABAA\: ABABA\: BABAB$

How can I find this result without literally counting them one by one?

Extra question: Can the result be extended to a tournament where n consecutive wins or n+1 total wins determines the winner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one way for a specific player to win after 2, 3, or 4 games.  (For instance the only way for B to win in 3 games is $ABB$.)

So there are $6$ sequences for the match to end in less than $5$ games.

For the match to end in $5$ games, the first four games must alternate winners (2 ways to do that), and the fifth game can have either player winning (2 ways to do that).  So there are $2\cdot 2=4$ ways for a 5-game match to occur.

So there are $10$ total sequences.

Honestly, listing out is probably just as easy; but this method might be good for a longer sequence.  For instance if winning the match required a player to win $2$ consecutive games or $7$ total, there would be $10+4=14$ possible sequences.

---

Edit/correction: As pointed out by kerizthemathgrad (thanks!) for $2$ consecutive wins or $7$ wins total, the correct answer is $26$. There could be alternation for up to 12 games. I incorrectly thought alternation for up to 6 games.

Comment: An interesting question, which the OP is in essence asking is:  "In a two-player tournament, the winner is the first to reach $m$ wins or $n<m$ sequential wins.  How many distinct sequences of tournaments exist?"

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It will get more complicated if the consecutive win condition is higher than $2$.

Comment: Of course it will get more complicated!  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521236/number-of-sequences-with-a-given-termination-conditions

Comment: Are you sure about the 14 possible sequences? If I am not mistaken, it should be 26. (AA BAA ABAA BABAA ABABAA BABABAA ABABABAA BABABABAA ABABABABAA BABABABABAA ABABABABABAA BABABABABABAA ABABABABABABA makes 13, alternating the letters gives 26). I think the formula for a tournament where the winner is first to achieve 2 consecutive wins or n total wins is 4n-2.

Comment: @kerizthemathgrad You are correct. Thanks for the catch. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

At each stage of the tournament, to be able to decide when it ends we want to keep track of the number of games each player has won, and the length of each player's current "streak" (0 if the player lost the previous game).  I'll call this information the current "state". We can then recursively compute the number of
possible outcomes starting in a given state.  If the rules say the tournament ends when this state occurs, that number is $1$, else it is the sum of the numbers for the states that occur as a result of each player winning the next game.

Comment: The general question was posted [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351141/number-of-sequences-satisfying-termination-conditions), and I used essentially this same idea in my answer.