# Number of sequences with given termination conditions

Tags: combinatorics

This question is a generalization of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521206/how-many-outcomes-does-the-chess-tournament-have):

Two players play a tournament of games of chess where the tournament winner is the first to achieve either $m>0$ total game wins or $0<n<m$ game wins in a row. (There are no ties.)  How many distinct possible sequences of game results exist as a function of $n$ and $m$?

For small values, one can write out the sequences (as in the linked question).

Clearly the *shortest* sequence of games is of length $n$ (of which there are two) and *longest* sequence of games is of length $2 m - 1$, but we seek the total number of *distinct sequences*.

---

***First steps***

Assume, without loss of generality, that the winning player is $A$ and the loser is $B$.

Let $0<k<2m-1$ be the *length* of a sequence.  If $k<n$ there is no tournament winner; we can ignore such cases.

There are, then, two ranges of interest:

- $n \leq k < m$
- $m \leq k \leq 2m -1$

In the *first* case, the only way $A$ wins the tournament is to win $n$ games in a row.  Of course the last game (position $k$) $A$ wins, terminating the tournament.  Thus the final $n$ games $A$ must win.  That leaves $k-n$ preceding "other" slots.  The last one of these must be won by $B$.  Thus there are $k - n - 1$ remaining "unassigned" slots which can be won in any order so long as $A$ does not win $n$ in a row.

The number of ways this can be achieved is:

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-n-1} {k-n-1 \choose j}$$

but again, this overcounts in certain cases because it includes cases in which $A$ wins $n$ consecutive games.

In the *second* case there are two categories of ways $A$ wins:  by winning $m$ games or by winning $n$ in a row.  In either of these cases, the last game (slot $k$) $A$ must win.  If $A$ wins $m$ total games (on the $k$th game) then $A$ has won $m-1$ games in the $2m - 2$, and that means that $B$ has won the remaining $m-1$ games (but neither have won $n$ in a row).

The total number of ways this can be done is:

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1} {2m - 2 \choose j}$$

but note that some of these cases may have $A$ win $n$ in a row.  We must subtract those cases.

Comment: You also have included in your count the cases where $B$ wins $n$ consecutive games, unless you first count only those cases where s/he does not. 

Counting $n$-length binary strings without a run of $k$ ones has been analyzed, see [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6937/e69f4c2b92aabaa52d0382ccd181816581f2.pdf), but you will need to count $n$-length binary strings without *any* run of $k$.

Comment: @rogerl:  I'm assuming that $A$ is the tournament winner.  If $B$ was the winner (i.e., before $A$) we merely interchange labels $A \leftrightarrow B$ and consider the shorter sequence that terminated the tournament.  But you're right that this condition has to be included in the calculation.  Your link helps, but is far from sufficient.  To me the core computational difficulty is including the "OR" in the two ways a player can win the tournament.

Comment: Agreed. Possibly you can define recurrences by letting $P(n,m,k)$ and $Q(n,m,k)$ be the number of ways of winning in exactly $k$ moves by the two methods, but my head hurts trying to think about double counting when defining the recurrence.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351141/number-of-sequences-satisfying-termination-conditions).